# Change which UserControl is display in the MainWindow within another UserControl C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application a have a mainwindow with a listview and a method where i change which usercontrol is displayed:

```
UserControl usc = null;
        GridMain.Children.Clear();

        switch (((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name)
        {
            case "ItemHome":
                usc = new UserControlCreate();
                GridMain.Children.Add(usc);
                break;
            case "ItemCreate":
                usc = new UserControlHome();
                GridMain.Children.Add(usc);
                break;
            case "ItemChange":
                usc = new Aenderungen();
                GridMain.Children.Add(usc);
                break;
            default:
                break;
```

now I am in the User Control "Aenderungen" and i want do change the displayed `UserControl` back to "ItemCreate" with a click on a `Textbox`.

How can i do that?

Comment: Your GridMain should be a ContentControl that uses different ContentTemplates, depending on the value of its Content property. ContentTemplates are DataTemplates that may be automatically selected via their DataType property. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: Can you please stop putting your logic into your code behind. There is so many great framwork to work with MVVM, so many articles, so many tutorials. First use MVVM, after that I am sure that you will not ask this question. MVVM, Messaging, Notifications etc... will solve this issue. but please for god, use MVVM guys.